# Group result from web scrape into sections

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While trying to learn how to use Python for web scraping I've fetched a lunch menu from this http://bramatno8.kvartersmenyn.se/

The page is built like this:

```
<div class="menu">
<strong>Monday<br></strong>
<br>
Food 1<br>
Food 2
<br><br>
<strong>Tuesday<br></strong>
<br>
Food 3<br>
Food 4
<br><br>
<strong>Wednesday<br></strong>
<br>
Food 5<br>
Food 6
<br><br>
<strong>Thursday<br></strong>
<br>
Food 7<br>
Food 8
<br><br>
<strong>Friday<br></strong>
<br>
Food 9<br>
Food 10
<br><br>
</div>
```

So what I've got so far is this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://lunchmenu.com'

fetchlunch = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(fetchlunch.text, 'html.parser')

menu = soup.findAll(class_='menu')[0]

for br in menu.find_all('br'):
    br.replace_with('\n')

print(menu.get_text())
```

So this will print the whole menu for the week in one section.

What I would like to do is just get the menu for a day. i.e. if it's Tuesday only the menu for Tuesday should show. So I guess I need to have the result in an array to then pull the menu for the day?

Comment: it's just an example. I want to scrape some local lunch menus to later being able to display them by current day. So what's for lunch on monday?

Comment: it's exactly as in that example.

Comment: here's an example of a lunchmenu http://www.kvartersmenyn.se/rest/15494

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to find the `<strong>` tag with matching day content, then use `.next_siblings` to iterate forward through the foods until you hit another `<strong>` or exhaust the siblings. I used the `lxml` parser but this works with `html.parser` as well.

Here it is in your sample DOM (I adjusted the foods to make it clear that it works):

```
import bs4
import requests

day = "Tuesday"
dom = """
<div class="menu">
<strong>Monday</strong>
<br>
Food 1<br>
Food 2
<br><br>
<strong>Tuesday</strong>
<br>
Food 3<br>
Food 4
<br><br>
<strong>Wednesday</strong>
<br>
Food 5<br>
Food 6
<br><br>
<strong>Thursday</strong>
<br>
Food 7<br>
Food 8
<br><br>
<strong>Friday</strong>
<br>
Food 9<br>
Food 10
<br><br>
</div>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(dom, "lxml")
menu = soup.find(class_ = "menu")
foods = []

for elem in menu.find("strong", text=day).next_siblings:
    if elem.name == "strong": 
        break

    if isinstance(elem, bs4.element.NavigableString) and elem.strip() != "":
        foods.append(elem.strip())

print(foods)
```

Output:

```
['Food 3', 'Food 4']
```

---

Here it is on the first live site https://www.kvartersmenyn.se/rest/15494. Note the extended character encoding and lambda to make the match work in case there is extra content in the `<b>` tag:

```
# -*- coding: latin1 -*-

import bs4
import requests

day = "Måndag"
url = "https://www.kvartersmenyn.se/rest/15494"

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
menu = soup.find(class_ = "meny")
foods = []

for elem in menu.find("b", text = lambda x: day in x).next_siblings:
    if elem.name == "b": 
        break

    if isinstance(elem, bs4.element.NavigableString):
        foods.append(elem)

print(day)

for food in foods:
    print(food)
```

Output:

```
Måndag
A: Gaeng phed**
röd curry i cocosmjölk med sötbasilika, wokade blandade grönsaker
B: Ghai phad med mauang** (biff) wok i chilipaste med cashewnötter, grönsaker
C: Phad bamme (fläsk) wokade äggnudlar i ostronsås, grönsaker
D: Satay gay currymarinerade kycklingfiléspett med jordnötssås
E: Gai chup pheng tood*
Friterad kyckling med söt chilisås och ris
F: Phad bambou* (biff) wok i ostronsås med bambu, lök, champinjoner
```

---

Finally, here it is on your second live site, http://bramatno8.kvartersmenyn.se/
. All of these sites have different and inconsistent structure, so it's not obvious if there's a silver bullet for them all. I suspect these menus are being coded by hand by someone who may not understand document structuring, so it'll take some work to handle arbitrary updates to the page.

Here goes:

```
# -*- coding: latin1 -*-

import bs4
import requests

day = "Måndag"
url = "http://bramatno8.kvartersmenyn.se/"

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
menu = soup.find(class_ = "meny")
foods = []

for elem in menu.find(text = day).parent.next_siblings:
    if elem.name == "strong": 
        break

    if isinstance(elem, bs4.element.NavigableString):
        foods.append(elem)

print(day)

for food in foods:
    print(food)
```

Output:

```
Måndag
Viltskav med rårörda lingon (eko), vaxbönor och potatispuré
Sesambakad blomkål med sojamarinerade böngroddar, salladslök, rädisa och sojabönor samt ris
```

Comment: Hmm now the menu I try to get they have added a <br> so it won't longer match the day. <strong>Måndag<br /></strong>

Comment: Thanks had to write lambda x: day in day to make it work but don't get the right menu if I  change day. Still get the menu for Monday

Comment: `lambda x: day in day` will always return true, so it's not a very meaningful construct. With the new menu, you need `for elem in menu.find(text = day).parent.next_siblings:` because the `text` property refers to the `<br>`. You can also strip out `<br>` tags from `<strong>`s first using `.extract()`. Do you have any other menus to scrape? Which are you trying to optimize for? If they're randomly using `<b>` vs `<strong>` and throwing `<br>`s in arbitrarily, that's a pretty important thing to state in your original question. In other words, try to post all the possible DOMs you want to match.

Comment: Ok thanks I will fiddle some more, one menu I use is this http://bramatno8.kvartersmenyn.se

Comment: You'll need to post more details than that. My code works on your original document, so if you want my answer to extrapolate to different DOMs, you should make a list of all the documents you're trying to scrape in the original question with sufficient details and examples showing your desired output, or open a fresh question if this one is solved and your requirements are drastically different, otherwise you're moving the goalpost.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate all the help I get here I've updated my question with the new DOM that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Updated. As you can see, even small adjustments to the DOM are going to require changes to the code, so if you need a more general scraper, you'll need to enumerate all possible markups and work from there rather than playing whack-a-mole like we're doing here.

Comment: Thanks learned a lot from your help also thanks for your patience :)

Comment: No problem--I also learned a lot writing these answers. Happy coding.